# Prometheus is scraping from offline target

Tags: prometheus, offline, target

i'm using Docker cAdvisor to monitor docker containers and Prometheus to scrape the cAdvisor endpoint. However, if i turn off cAdvisor and all my docker containers, Prometheus is continiung to show me actual data from the offline targets for another 5 minutes. After those 5 minute the graph-line disappears. Is this behavior intentional? And how can i change it so that when the target endpoint is not reachable, Prometheus does not show any data?

I have added an image for better understanding:
[image]

Prometheus is configured to scrape data every 5 seconds.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add `--query.lookback-delta=XXs` as a flag when running Prometheus.